# Merge SwiftyJson Multiple Arrays

Tags: json, swift, swift3, swifty-json

I am using `SwiftyJSON` in `Swift` and I have three arrays that I would like to merge together into one array. If the name already exist, i'll like it to add the value to just get one element.

These are the arrays that I have:

```
var array1 = JSON(
        "name" : "apple",
        "Value" : 2
    ]

var array2 = JSON(
        "name" : "apple",
        "Value" : 4
    ]

var array3 = JSON(
        "name" : "orange",
        "Value" : 10
    ]
```

What is the best way to achieve the result below when I print the array?

```
{ 
{
   "name": "apple"
   "value": 6
}   {
   "name": "orange"
   "value": 10
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: so i am assuming you have different arrays that are all let say fruit Type ?

Comment: These are not arrays, they are JSON (converted by using swiftyjson). I'v tried many things mainly messing around with for loops. That is the wrong approach tho.